# Sending a SMS Message from an Android Application without opening chooser?

Tags: android, sms, android-implicit-intent

In my android application I have implemented sending SMS by using below code.

```
   Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello World!"); 
    smsIntent.putExtra("address", "0123456789");
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

    startActivity(smsIntent);
```

My problem is that if I have more than one SMS application on the device, it opens the chooser to choose the sender application. I don't want the chooser to be opened; I want to send from Android's native SMS app without opening the chooser. So any help to achieve this will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Android OS will always give the user the option of choosing another application. Unless they chose to always use a specific application for this kind of action.
Besides if the user has installed an other application for sms, they will probably prefer to use the application that they prefer, not the application that you prefer.

Comment: who is that intelligent person down Voted. is it not seems to be a reasonable question? its my client requirement for one of their banking application. AS it is a Financial related app client want to send SMS through a proper channel only and not from some 3rd party app.

Comment: Downvotes without comments explaining why !== constructive criticism. Come on folks, if you don't like Raj's question, help him write a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SMS Manager?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

```
void    sendTextMessage(String destinationAddress, String scAddress, String text, PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent)
```

Send a text based SMS.

Answer (score 5):

> In my android application i have implemented sending SMS by using below code.

That is not the proper way to send SMS messages. Please use `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_SENDTO` (the latter with an `smsto:` `Uri`). You may encounter devices which can send SMS messages but do not respond to the particular `Intent` structure that you are using, since that is not the way to send SMS messages.

> I don't want that chooser to be opened

If your user chose to install another SMS client, they have the right to use it, since it is their device, their SMS message fee, etc. The user can elect to make your app be the default for your `Intent` structure if the user chooses to do so, so the user will not be presented with the chooser all of the time.

> I wants to send from android Native SMS app without opening chooser

Different devices can have different "native SMS apps", put their by device manufacturers, so you have no means of determining what is the "native SMS app". And, as I noted earlier, the "native SMS app" may not even respond to that strange `Intent` structure that you are using.

Comment: your true, i.e user will have right to use any 3rd party apps. but its my client requirement for one of their banking application. AS it is a Financial related app and client want to send SMS through a proper channel only and not from some 3rd party app.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm afraid you will have to tell your client to live with this. It's the same with for example opening an url, the user will also get the choice of browser (unless a default one is selected). And every manufacturer has it's own browser etc. And a lot of users prefer to have a different browser than the standard one. It's the same with the sms application.

Comment: @Raj: "AS it is a Financial related app and client want to send SMS through a proper channel only and not from some 3rd party app" -- they are *all* third-party apps from the standpoint of the bank. The bank is welcome to use `SmsManager` and send the SMS directly themselves, bypassing any of the clients. **THE COMPLETE AND ENTIRE POINT BEHIND `ACTION_SEND` AND KIN IS TO GIVE THE USER CONTROL**. If you do not want to give the user control, do not use such `Intent` structures, but do the work yourself.

Comment: @commonsWare: thanks for your suggestion and your valuable time on my issue.