# Android SMS Via Intent Without Chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

Can someone show me a snippet of code that calls the SMS app via an intent **without** having the chooser appear?

I've seen this done in other apps and in particular I'm trying to do this from within an InputService (keyboard).  I've created a keyboard that has custom images and need to pass one to the SMS window.  Only way to do that is to create an intent with the image but each time the chooser opens up and I have to select the SMS app as the recipient.  Now I know that once the user selects the "Always use this" option it won't happen again but I'd prefer them not to have to do that.

Here's the code I'm using now that works except for the chooser appearing:

```
fmImageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap b = fmImageView.getDrawingCache();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath+"/sms.png");
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
File f = new File(filePath+"/sms.png");

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: This question has already been asked an answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261025/sending-a-sms-message-from-an-android-application-without-opening-chooser

Comment: If there is a chooser appearing, then the user has two or more apps advertising themselves as SMS clients, and you have no way of knowing which of those SMS clients the user wants to use. Please allow the user to use the SMS client of the *user's* choice.

Comment: I have to disagree with the user having to select the SMS client.  There is an external keyboard available right now called USC Trojans (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snaps.bradz.usc_torjan_keyboard)  that does exactly what I'm attempting to do.   When in the keyboard it basically calls itself and adds the image to the SMS body.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this rather than "image/png" -

`shareIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");`

Comment: Yes I've tried that before and the problem is that the image does not appear in the sms body.