# Android intent.setType("String value")

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I have read [documentation of setType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType(java.lang.String)) but arguments are not mentioned. Where can I read full possible string arguments that use inside setType() keyword. I need information on **setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms")**. I am working on some messaging app and this setType works fine with me. It takes user to default messaging app. What I want is open write message box in default messaging app. I use code like below, but it only takes me to inbox.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
 intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms/"+phone_number_in_string);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is open write message box in default messaging app.

Use `putExtra`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms/");
intent.putExtra("address", phone_number_in_string);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", " ");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It's working but It pops up a chooser for opening messaging app. Is there a way to bypass it? ACTION_MAIN doesn't ask about it

Comment: use [SMSManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) for this. But [If ur user chose 2 install another SMS client, they have the right 2 use it, since it is their device, their SMS message fee. The user can elect to make your app be the default for your Intent structure if the user chooses to do so, so the user will not be presented with the chooser all of the time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261025/sending-a-sms-message-from-an-android-application-without-opening-chooser) from [CommonsWare](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware).

Comment: I am getting one problem using this, It works  great with the first time but when I again do by changing the number from app it takes me to the previous number writebox. I have to clear the app to work again then problem continues..

Comment: @HackingActivities, I dont think this error, coz I'm using the same code now.

Comment: But why I am facing so?? It took me whole day. Clearing app reinstalling, watching my code first to last more than 50 times but I could not fix it and now I give up. I used previous one Action.Main instead  of Action.View. If you do not mind  can u tell me username of your developer console??